# Stop line animation in between at center

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want this line will move smoothly from right to left but at the center it will stop for 4-5 seconds. Here we can also add some more lines,when first line came to center from right side ,it stops there and wait for another lines and when all lines came at center then all lines stop there for few seconds then again lines start moving in right side. This will continue for infinite loop.

```css
.spinner {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: red;
  animation: load 5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

#div {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 1, 1);
}

@keyframes load {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 80%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 45%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div" class="spinner"></div>
```

Comment: but what about this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241155/creating-a-loader-in-which-lines-making-a-circle-at-center you don't need it anymore? you souldn't ask a question then leave to ask another one

Answer (score 0):

To "hold" the *animation* for *4 s* means it will take *80%* of the *initial animation duration* you defined. So in order to do that, just define the middle *keyframe* to span from `10%` to `90%`, leaving equal amount of *10%* on both sides:

```css
.spinner {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; 
  width: 150px;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: red; 
  animation: load 5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

#div {animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,1,1,1)}

@keyframes load {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 80%;      
  }
  10%, 90% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 45%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div" class="spinner"></div>
```